# How to lower both indices on the metric tensor?

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

If I have the tensor matrix $g^{\mu \nu}$ and I want the tensor matrix too $g_{\mu \nu}$, what is the calculation? Inverse? Adjoint? Some rule?

Answer (score 1):

There is a relation that people come across while doing tensor calculus. That is
$$
g_{\nu \mu } g^{\mu \alpha } = \delta^{\alpha}_{\nu}
$$

So, yes! $g_{\mu \nu }$ is inverse of $g^{\mu \nu }$ and vice versa. So, just invert one to get the other.

Comment: thank you for bringing it to my notice. I've corrected my answer. Don't know what I was thinking. @J.Murray

Comment: No problem - I'll delete my comment.